# how to use eclipse workspace on different computers

Tags: eclipse

I have 3 developer machines (office desk, office laptop and home laptop) and I would like to keep my eclipse workspace and projects on usb drive and use it on all 3 computers... is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is possible by indicating the folder on your usb to be your workspace, I'd recommend using [version control](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) if you have access to some server. This way you can work on your projects anywhere, have constant backup, and keep track of the changes.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible if one of the pcs is behind a proxy that doesn't allow the vcs to pass.

Comment: Additional info after some research: you can host a git repo on a local machine too. So go with vcs!

Answer (score 1):

Try using dropbox folders for  your workspace (with their packrat feature its even better). That will keep all your files up to date :D.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Copy the workspace folder to your usb drive and open the workspace from any Eclipse installation you want to.

By the way, it may be a better idea to use a [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system. Sure, you'd have to synchronize your workspace every time you make a change in the code and commit it, but usb drives can get lost, or stolen, and I'm sure you wouldn't want to lose all of your projects if you lost your usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Change your workspace to point to your shared drive. This is easier on OS's like linux as you can mount the USB drive to a specific directory.

Or, do what I do and copy the workspace directory for specific projects from one machine to another. This was covered here :
[How to share eclipse configuration over different workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078476/how-to-share-eclipse-configuration-over-different-workspaces)