# Eclipse sharing plugins between workspaces

Tags: eclipse

I usually have a different workspace for each project that I work on (perl, java, PHP, etc.). Sometimes, I find a common new plugin (say EGIT) and install it , but it doesn't show up automatically in the other workspaces. Is there some setting in eclipse where I can enable this? I am using Indigo SR2.

Thanks!

P.S.: I know we have working sets within workspaces to help re-use the same workspace, but sometimes it is easier to manage projects when in separate workspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Eclipse Indigo onwards, there is a way to [import installations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11264964/874076) which makes it available across workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the same Eclipse installation, each plug-in that you install will be available in all workspaces. You can see the list of installed plug-ins by selecting `Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details`

Comment: Not true. We have a single instance of eclipse shared by users with different workspaces. It won't show up in the installation details and it won't appear for usage

Answer (score 1):

To go with rgerganov's answer: 
For certain plugins, although they're installed and available to all workspaces for a given Eclipse installation, they may need to be individually configured within each workspace.
An example of this is the Checkstyle plugin where you need to specify the configuration to use, and enable it for each project within the workspace. This may also be the case for EGit.

Comment: As rgerganov rightly pointed out, the plugins are showing up in the installation details, but where do I specify "configuration" for it to be usable? You can use Checkstyle as an example as I have a problem with that plugin as well. Thank!

Comment: Running blind here as I don't have Eclipse near me at the moment, but from memory you right-click on the project in the workspace explorer, click on the "Checkstyle" context menu, and select
"Configure Checkstyle". From within the configuration menu you can point it to a file location (or other suitable options). Sorry for the vagueness. If you can't find the option, let me know and I'll take a look when I can.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I had to use the trick mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078476/how-to-share-eclipse-configuration-over-different-workspaces) of copying the relevant prefs files from one of the workspace directory to the new workspace directory followed by an eclipse restart to get the plugins enabled. Others feel free to edit if you see a better way.