# SVN Unversion equivalent for ClearCase

Tags: eclipse, maven, clearcase

we have started a project versioned with ClearCase (sadly).
We also use Maven and ClearCase eclipse plug-in. Each time I build a project, a popup shows up (which says Add items in target folder to source control) and drives me mad. It pauses the build process so I have to check frequently to resume process.

Is there a way to ignore and unversion this folder like with SVN? I've added target folder to ignored sources on eclipse but pop-up still appears

Comment: Which popup do you see?

Comment: @VonC: add to source control popup. i will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the "Add Elements to Source Control" dialog box:

[image: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0919_arif_siefkes/image004.jpg]

<sup>(Source: "[Using ClearCase with Rational Performance Tester](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0919_arif_siefkes/)")</sup>

The workaround is:

> - On the main menu, click `Windows > Preferences`.
> - In the left pane, expand Team and then select ClearCase SCM Adapter
> - Change the preference for `When new resources are added` to `Do nothing` (from the default value of `Prompt to add to source control`).

Comment: Thank you. This will ease my problem. Yet it also creates a problem that I have to be aware when adding new class or file. Ignoring target folder is real solution to me

Comment: @ErcanÖzdemir you can set that setting for an Eclipse workspace, dedicated for build, which can be different from your dev Eclipse workspace (you can switch workspaces and have different settings, as illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2078547/6309)