# Java - Rational Team Concert - Load more than one stream workspace at same time

Tags: java, eclipse, rtc, jazz

We have a project in RTC with 2 streams:

```
PROJECT-MAIN (component src)
  - ear
  - web
  - ejb
PROJECT-RELEASE-1.0.0 (component src)
  - ear
  - web
  - ejb
```

We loaded the `PROJECT-MAIN` and in the package explorer Eclipse displays the projects as ear, web and ejb.

But now, I need to work at `PROJECT-RELEASE-1.0.0`, how could I load it? I ask this, because, if I load it even in another folder (sandbox), the projects names (ear, web and ejb) has conflicts in package explorer.

How do Java EE developers work with RTC?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to switch Eclipse workspace in order to work in main in one workspace, and on 1.0.0 on the other.

In each Eclipse workspace, you can load the same eclipse projects.

You can switch workspace with the menu "`File > Switch workspace`".

[image: Switch Workspace in RTC]

Note that on switching workspace, you will have to create again your RTC repository connection.
But once that it is done (only on the first switch), you will find back all your repo workspaces.

Comment: At first, thank you for reply VonC. I've already heard this answer before.(Some consultors o IBM already have told me this), but I think that is not the best solution. We need to configure our workspace again and again for each Stream. What's about just use a GENERIC workspace and just reply content with target stream ? (changing the flow too) ? I think it's equivalent to GIT CHECKOUT, (keeping the same folder to all streams). What do you thing ? thanks.

Comment: @Denny If the number of streams is fixed, that should limit the number of configurations. I am not aware of another solution that might use only one Eclipse workspace. But configuring a new eclipse workspace can be scripted: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2078547/6309 (you could copy and modify the content of one workspace setting into another).