# Sharing an Eclipse workspace between two computers

Tags: eclipse

What is a "safe" way to share an Eclipse workspace between two computers? I've had problems using Dropbox and I've had problems using Github. I am looking for a best practice that will "just work".

#### Update

I read below and many other places that sharing a workspace doesn't work. But my collection includes 50 projects, are you saying that I need to create 50 github repos? There's no way to put them all in one repo to save the repetition?

#### Solution (imperfect, but still improving)

My collection of projects is in a github repo called projects/ which includes 50 subdirectories, each structured appropriately as they would be for an eclipse project.The /projects directory doesn't have meta-data or any other eclipse info (AFAIK)

Separately, in ~ I create a brand new Eclipse workspace. And then I "manually" import each one with Eclipse. I do this on each machine that needs to access those projects via Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

No, the workspace will contain machine-specific information and locations. Share the projects themselves, preferably through a source code management system like git. If anything in the project refers to something outside the workspace, you'll want it changed to refer to that resource in a portable way (e.g. pick the JRE using an Execution Environment instead by name).

Comment: I've updated my question above accordingly. Am I now on the right track?

Comment: You can put all of the projects in a single repo, just not the workspace itself. It's not that uncommon; https://github.com/cloudbees/cloudbees-eclipse is all projects, but not a workspace. The Git Repositories view can be used to import them after you clone the repo.

Comment: One follow up. I have all my projects now in their own parent directory (which will goto git). I have delted .meta-data from that parent so AFAIK there is no eclipse specific stuff. Now I create a brand new workspace based in ~ so there's no old Eclipse there either. Yet, when import all the project directories, only a subset are recognized as projects and imported. Any idea?

Comment: Eclipse recognizes projects because of the .project file--were they all committed to the branch? If they're Maven projects, it's the one time to use the Maven project importer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the thread at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799711/10235188. They describe how to share a workspace and configurations between machines. Otherwise you'll always have problems with absolute paths.