# Sharing A Project Between 2 Computers

Tags: java, eclipse

Im a college student with a laptop and a desktop but I want to have a shared eclipse workspace that automatically updates whatever changes Ive made to the shared files.

Edit:
Github is the best way to do this as with a single command you can download/update the code and be working within seconds of that command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing an Eclipse workspace between two computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54315349/sharing-an-eclipse-workspace-between-two-computers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a student, i suggest of using [GITHUB desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).
very easy to use for first git users.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better and the most general way is using git control version system for this. If you want something is like in live stream it is going to cause a lot of editing problems because of synchronization issues.