# How do I have my compileSdk set to a certain value by default on every new Android project creation?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have been having a problem for some time now. In **build.gradle** I have always had my `compileSdk` set to 32. And it would never prevent my app from starting.

Since recent times, when I start a new Android project and run it, the compiler outputs an error that tells me to update my `compileSdk`, as *there are dependencies that require libraries and applications that depend  on them to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs*.

I know I have to go to my **build.gradle (app/module)** file and change `compileSdk` to 33. But the difficulty is that I have to do that every time I start a new Android project. Please tell me how I could make it so `compileSdk`'s value is always set to 33, by default.

Google did not help, I've not been able to find a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an IDE? If so, you should be able to set this up in the project creation wizard. If I am not mistaken, You should be able to set minimum SDK in those configurations. Most IDEs also have a configuration profile with which you can use to replicate those settings each time you create a new project. Here is a few to get you started. Android Studio is sure to have this feature.

[VS Code Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

[Settings for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078476/how-to-share-eclipse-configuration-over-different-workspaces)

[Android Studio Settings](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config)