# How to copy a directory structure but only include certain files

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I found a solution for my question in Windows but I'm using Ubuntu: [How to copy a directory structure but only include certain files using Windows batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472692/)

As the title says, how can I recursively copy a directory structure but only include some files?  For example, given the following directory structure:

```
folder1
  folder2
    folder3
      data.zip
      info.txt
      abc.xyz
    folder4
    folder5
      data.zip
      somefile.exe
      someotherfile.dll
```

The files **data.zip** and **info.txt** can appear everywhere in the directory structure. How can I copy the full directory structure, but only include files named `data.zip` and `info.txt` (all other files should be ignored)?

The resulting directory structure should look like this:

```
copy_of_folder1
  folder2
    folder3
      data.zip
      info.txt
    folder4
    folder5
      data.zip
```

Could you tell me a solution for Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of [Bash: copy named files recursively preserving folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650164/) — form 2009 — other than the fact that there's currently a bounty running on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a beautiful one liner, but since nobody else has answered you can always:

```
find . -name 'file_name.extension' -print | cpio -pavd /path/to/receiving/folder
```

For each specific file after copying the directories.

(Make sure you're in the original folder first, of course! :) )

Comment: Hi, This doesn't solve the issue as need to copy everything manually

Comment: @ayniam: what do you mean by 'copy everything manually'?  The whole point of using `cpio` is to let the machine do the copying.

Answer (score 6):

```bash
$ rsync --recursive --include="data.zip" --include="*.txt" --filter="-! */" dir_1 copy_of_dir_1
```

To exclude `dir3` regardless of where it is in the tree (even if it contains files that would match the `--include`s):

```
--exclude 'dir3/' (before `--filter`)
```

To exclude `dir3` only at at specific location in the tree, specify an absolute path, starting from your source dir:

```
--exclude '/dir1/dir2/dir3/' (before `--filter`)
```

To exclude `dir3` only when it's in `dir2`, but regardless of where `dir2` is:

```
--exclude 'dir2/dir3/' (before `--filter`)
```

Wildcards can also be used in the path elements where `*` means a directory with any name and `**` means multiple nested directories.

To specify only files and dirs to include, run two `rsync`s, one for the files and one for the dirs. The problem with getting it done in a single `rsync` is that when you don't include a dir, `rsync` won't enter the dir and so won't discover any files in that branch that may be matching your include filter. So, you start by copying the files you want while not creating any dirs that would be empty. Then copy any dirs that you want.

```
$ rsync --recursive --prune-empty-dirs --include="*.txt" --filter="-! */" dir_1 copy_of_dir_1
$ rsync --recursive --include '/dir1/dir2/' --include '/dir3/dir4/' --filter="-! */" dir_1 copy_of_dir_1
```

You can combine these if you don't mind that your specified dirs don't get copied if they're empty:

```
$ rsync --recursive --prune-empty-dirs --include="*.txt" --include '/dir1/dir2/' --include '/dir3/dir4/' --filter="-! */" dir_1 copy_of_dir_1
```

The `--filter="-! */"` is necessary because rsync includes all files and folders that match none of the filters (imagine it as an invisible `--include` filter at the end of the list of filters). `rsync` checks each item to be copied against the list of filters and includes or excludes the item depending on the first match it finds. If there's no match, it hits that invisible `--include` and goes on to include the item. We wanted to change this default to `--exclude`, so we added an exclude filter (the `-` in `-! */`), then we negate the match (`!`) and match all dirs (`*/`). Since this is a negated match, the result is that we allow `rsync` to enter all the directories (which, as I mentioned earlier, allows `rsync` to find the files we want).

We use `--filter` instead of `--exclude` for the final filter because `--exclude` does not allow specifying negated matches with the `!` operator.

Comment: Thanks Roger Dahl, This is working fine. However, need a scalable solution. As in real world, we can't include so many folder names in an exclude flag . The files to be included should be parameterised as in the windows solution present above. How can I just include the directories and files needed and exclude all other folders and files,preserving the folder structure at the same time.  Secondly, please let me know why a filter rule is needed here as we are including and excluding required files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using rsync:

```
 rsync -a -f"+ info.txt" -f"+ data.zip" -f'-! */' folder1/ copy_of_folder1/
```

If you already have a file list, and want a more scalable solution

```
 cat file.list | xargs -i rsync -a -f"+ {}" -f'-! */' folder1/ copy_of_folder1/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -pr folder1 copy_of_folder1; find copy_of_folder1 -type f ! \( -name data.zip -o -name info.txt \)  -exec rm -f {} \;
```

- first time : copy entirely  folder1 to copy_of_folder1
- second time :    erase all files differents from data.zip and
  info.txt
- At the end, you have your complete structure with only the file data.zip and info.txt

Comment: Hi Michel, this is not scalable as we need to copy 70 gb of data and again erase most of it. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Hi ayniam, you are right, 70 gb is a bit too much for this kind of procedure. But i don't understand why Chan Than need the full structure even if directory are empty. Have a good day.