# Copy entire folder structure in Powershell without re-creating root folder

Tags: powershell

I have a source folder like this:

```
source_folder -|
               |-> sub_folder1
               |-> sub_folder2
               |-> sub_folder3
```

where `sub_folder1`, `sub_folder2` and `sub_folder3` have themselves got sub-folders and files.  I also have an existing empty folder `dest_folder` and I want to end up with:

```
dest_folder -|
             |-> sub_folder1
             |-> sub_folder2
             |-> sub_folder3
```

where the sub-folders are copies of the first lot.  I tried `Copy-Item source_folder dest_folder -Recurse` but that left me with:

```
dest_folder -|
             |-> source_folder -|
                                |-> sub_folder1
                                |-> sub_folder2
                                |-> sub_folder3
```

It seems like this should be possible with a simple `Copy-Item` if only I could find the right combination of wildcards and switches!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Copy-Item C:\source\* C:\dest -Recurse
```

Works for me

Comment: (changed my mind - this might help someone as the docs are not clear on this point).  I thought I'd tried this but obviously mistyped/did something stupid!  Anyhow this works fine.

Comment: this doesn't work with -filter option if you have subfolders

Comment: @AndreiM Remove the `\*` from the source path, and delete the destination first. `rm -r -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue C:\dest; Copy-Item C:\source C:\dest -Recurse -Filter "*.txt"`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29082938/438664

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because i used this command without the * you get the result as you had.

```
Copy-Item C:\source C:\dest -Recurse
```

Comment: did you mean C:\source\* ?