# Copy-Item without source directory

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm trying to mirror a few folders for a simple backup system.

Let's assume I have the following file structure:

```
c:\temp\a.txt
c:\temp\b.txt
c:\temp\sub\a.txt
c:\temp\sub\112233.txt
c:\temp\sub2\pictureofaduck.jpg
```

My objective is to copy the whole content of `c:\temp\` to a new destination (`D:\mybackup\`) like this:

```
d:\mybackup\a.txt
d:\mybackup\b.txt
d:\mybackup\sub\a.txt
d:\mybackup\sub\112233.txt
d:\mybackup\sub2\pictureofaduck.jpg
```

I wrongly assumed that this should be an easy task for Copy-Item using this line:

```
Copy-Item 'C:\temp\' -Destination 'D:\mybackup\' -Recurse
```

Contrary to my expectation, `Copy-Item` is really eager to keep that "temp" folder in the game. Because what whatever wildcard and -at the end combinations I try, I either get the following result or only the two files a.txt & b.txt copied.

```
d:\mybackup\temp\a.txt
d:\mybackup\temp\b.txt
d:\mybackup\temp\sub\123.txt
d:\mybackup\temp\sub\112233.txt
d:\mybackup\temp\sub2\pictureofaduck.jpg
```

Please help me, this is ridiculous.

PS: the solution to this question here doesn't work - been there. I get only the root files:

[Copy entire folder structure in Powershell without re-creating root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986013/copy-entire-folder-structure-in-powershell-without-re-creating-root-folder)

Comment: Does this help?  `Copy-Item 'C:\temp\*' -Destination 'D:\mybackup\' -Recurse`

Comment: sorry powershell :) `xcopy C:\temp D:\mybackup /e`

Comment: @boxdog no this only copies the two root files.

Comment: I would suggest using RoboCopy.

Comment: @StefanLippeck.  Odd - worked when I tested it.  Maybe I missed something.  In any case, mirroring large folder structures is one of the few tasks I don't like to do in native PowerShell.  I have some similar backup jobs I run regularly that I do with RoboCopy: `RoboCopy /mir <source_dir> <dest_dir>`

Answer (score 3):

I'm really prefer `Xcopy` or `RoboCopy` for that jobs, but if you really want to use Copy-Item:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse | % {Copy-Item $_.FullName D:\mybackup}
```

using Xcopy:

```
xcopy C:\temp D:\mybackup /e
```

using RoboCopy:

```
robocopy C:\temp D:\mybackup /e
```

Comment: this brings me already a little closer, but in this case, all the files end up in D:\backup\ (and if there are files with the same name, they overwrite each other) - But you put me in the right direction. I'll put up my solution soon

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thanks to @Avshalom 's input.
I wrote myself a litte function for future usage:

```
function myCopyFolder([string] $sourceFolder, [string] $destFolder) {
    $i = 0
    Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder -Recurse | % {
        $destName = $_.FullName
        $destName = $destName.Replace($sourceFolder, '')
        Write-Host $_.FullName -Destination (Join-Path $destFolder $destName)
        $i = $i + 1
    }
    write-host $i 'files' copied
}
```

now i get a complete copy like xcopy would do it. I also tried implementing filters but with them i'd have to find a way to copy the folders separately if needed. - It does what i was looking for.

i added filtering by file type: (empty folders wont be copied with filter)

```
function myCopyFolder([string] $sourceFolder, [string] $destFolder, [string] $filter) {
    $i = 0
    Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder -Recurse -Filter $filter | % {
        $destName = $_.FullName
        $destName = $destName.Replace($sourceFolder, '')
        $subFolder = $destName.Replace($_.Name, '').Replace('\','')
        if ($subFolder -ne '') {
            if (-not (Test-Path (Join-Path $destFolder $subFolder))) {
                mkdir (Join-Path $destFolder $subFolder)
            }
        }
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination (Join-Path $destFolder $destName)
        $i = $i + 1
    }
    write-host $i 'files' copied
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the `[string]` type modifiers in the function definition may not be doing what you expect - they do not imply that you can only pass in strings, but instead mean "I'll accept anything that is a string or can be converted to one".  Since every object in .NET has a `ToString()` method anything (`Int`, `DateTime`, `WebClient`, `Guid`, etc) you pass will be accepted (i.e. converted to a string) and the resulting behaviour might be unexpected, even disastrous.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround might be to use `Copy-Item` followed by`Move-Item`

```
Copy-Item 'C:\temp\' -Destination 'D:\' -Recurse
Move-Item 'D:\temp\' -Destination 'D:\mybackup'
```

This does have the caveats that

- `D:\temp` doesn't already exists. If it does, you'll end up overwriting/moving other files
- `D:\mybackup` doesn't already exists